# Creating xor checksum of all bytes in hex string In Python

Tags: python, xor

While attempting to communicate with an audio processing device called BSS London Blu-80, I discovered I have to send a checksum created by Xoring the message.  An example message being sent would be:

```
0x8d 0x1e 0x19 0x1b 0x83 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x4b 0x00 0x00 0xc2
```

With 0xc2 being the correct checksum for that message.

"The checksum is a single-byte exclusive or(xor) of all the bytes in the message body."

The message body is that above minus the checksum.

The code I attempt however:

```
packet = '0x8d 0x1e 0x19 0x1b 0x83 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x4b 0x00 0x00'
xor = 0
i = 0
while i < len(packet):
    xor = xor ^ ord(packet[i])
    i += 1

>>print xor
46
>>print hex(xor)
'0x2e'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `packet = '\x8d\x1e\x19\x1b\x83\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x4b\x00\x00'`.

Comment: You can review your result here: th-thielemann.de/tools/checksum.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have declared `packet` as the **printable representation** of the message:

```
packet = '0x8d 0x1e 0x19 0x1b 0x83 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x4b 0x00 0x00'
```

so your current message is not `[0x8d, 0x1e, ..., 0x00]`, but `['0', 'x', '8', 'd', ..., '0']` instead. So, first step is fixing it:

```
packet = '0x8d 0x1e 0x19 0x1b 0x83 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x4b 0x00 0x00'
packet = [chr(int(x, 16)) for x in packet.split(' ')]
```

Or, you could consider encoding it "right" from the beginning:

```
packet = '\x8d\x1e\x19\x1b\x83\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x4b\x00\x00'
```

At this point, we can xor, member by member:

```
checksum = 0
for el in packet:
    checksum ^= ord(el)

print checksum, hex(checksum), chr(checksum)
```

the checksum I get is `0x59`, not `0xc2`, which means that either you have calculated the wrong one or the original message is not the one you supplied.

Comment: Well that just adds to the confusion. That message with checksum was generated by the tool used to test commands to different objects within the blu-10. When I copy that message and send it directly with Python, the state of the object changes.  So that checksum is correct for that string.

Comment: The documentation you are referring to says _"<checksum byte> is the exclusive OR of all the bytes in <body>, **before substitution**."_. I don't know what _"substitution"_ means here, but I guess the problem lies in what gets substituted.

Comment: You were exactly right.  The whole time I was thinking I wasn't substituting.  However, I never thought that the string generated from the DI tool was showing me a string WITH substitutions.. After removing '\x1b\x83' and replacing it with what it substitutes (\x03), then generating the checksum, I was able to return c2.  Thank you for bringing that to my attention!

Comment: Could you explain what was meant by "substitutions"? I am in a similar situation, but I cannot find anything explaining what that means.

Answer (score 0):

8 Bit Check sum Solution

> > > r=hex(0x37^0x37^0xA0^0x00^0x07^0x63^0x80^0x8A^0x05^0x0C)[2:].upper()

Result-'C7'